# Помогите пожалуйста переделать скрипт для Telegram Bot на aiogram

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, aiogram, python-telegram-bot

Уважаемые коллеги, здесь мне уже помогали переделать вот этот скрипт, который работал строго с aiogram==2.25.1, а нам нужно было чтобы он работал с aiogram3. Вот изначальный код:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3.9
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters import CommandStart, CommandHelp
from aiogram.types import Message
import configparser
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read("/etc/tgbot/settings.ini")
BOT_TOKEN = config["BOT"]["BOT_TOKEN"]
bot = Bot(BOT_TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher(bot = bot)
@dp.message_handler(CommandStart())
async def start(message: Message):
   await send_info(message)
@dp.message_handler(CommandHelp())
async def start(message: Message):
   await send_info(message)
async def send_info(message):
   text = '\n'.join(("Привет! Я телеграм бот.",
                     "Ваши данные:",
                    f"id: {message.from_user.id}",
                    f"first_name: {message.from_user.first_name}",
                    f"user_name: {message.from_user.username}"))
   await message.answer(text)
if __name__ == '__main__':
   executor.start_polling(dp)
```

Коллега со stackoverflow помог переделать код для aiogram3:

```
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher
from aiogram.filters import CommandStart, Command
from aiogram.types import Message
import configparser
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read("/etc/tgbot/settings.ini")
BOT_TOKEN = config["BOT"]["BOT_TOKEN"]
bot = Bot(BOT_TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher()

@dp.message(CommandStart())
async def start(message: Message):
   await send_info(message)
@dp.message(Command('help'))
async def start(message: Message):
   await send_info(message)
async def send_info(message:Message):
   text = '\n'.join(("Привет! Я телеграм бот.",
                     "Ваши данные:",
                    f"id: {message.from_user.id}",
                    f"first_name: {message.from_user.first_name}",
                    f"user_name: {message.from_user.username}"))
   await message.answer(text)
if __name__ == '__main__':
   dp.start_polling(bot)
```

Но теперь при запуске кода появляется такая ошибка:

> Ошибка в логах: app.py:25: RuntimeWarning: coroutine
> 'Dispatcher.start_polling' was never awaited dp.start_polling(bot)
> RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation
> traceback

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться, где тут ошибка. Я сисадмин, знаю корный пайтон, но в библиотеках для ботов не разбираюсь, буду очень благодарна!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NTA прав, но я бы ещё добавил то, что всю логику вашего бота стоит перенести в 1 функцию, так код станет более читабельным

```
import asyncio
import configparser

from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher
from aiogram.filters import CommandStart, Command
from aiogram.types import Message

config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read("/etc/tgbot/settings.ini")
BOT_TOKEN = config["BOT"]["BOT_TOKEN"]
bot = Bot(BOT_TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher()


@dp.message(CommandStart())
@dp.message(Command('help'))
async def start(message: Message):
    await message.answer("Привет! Я телеграм бот.\n"
                         "Ваши данные:\n"
                         f"id: {message.from_user.id}\n"
                         f"first_name: {message.from_user.first_name}\n"
                         f"user_name: {message.from_user.username}")


async def main():
    await dp.start_polling(bot)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: огромное вам спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 0):

Код немножко не правильно написан. start_polling это асинхронная функция.

```
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher
from aiogram.filters import CommandStart, Command
from aiogram.types import Message
from asycnio import run
import configparser
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read("/etc/tgbot/settings.ini")
BOT_TOKEN = config["BOT"]["BOT_TOKEN"]
bot = Bot(BOT_TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher()

@dp.message(CommandStart())
async def start(message: Message):
   await send_info(message)
@dp.message(Command('help'))
async def start(message: Message):
   await send_info(message)
async def send_info(message:Message):
   text = '\n'.join(("Привет! Я телеграм бот.",
                     "Ваши данные:",
                    f"id: {message.from_user.id}",
                    f"first_name: {message.from_user.first_name}",
                    f"user_name: {message.from_user.username}"))
   await message.answer(text)

async def main():
   await dp.start_polling(bot)

if __name__ == '__main__':
   run(main())
```

Comment: спасибо вам большое!